# Integration Kibana in my web application

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, proxy, kibana, pyramid

I implemented a web application with Pyramid and deployed it on Apache. moreover there are some other machines which inside of them I have Elastic db and Kibana Dashboard.
I want to show the dashboard of the Kibana inside of my web application.
more detais:

1) We have an elastic db where we store the information we want to show, together with what we need to identify who was working on the system, time after time.

2) We have a kibana dashboard that aggregates all the information from elastic.

What I need:

3) We need to filter the data in the dashboard according to the user logged in.

4) We need to place this filter in the URL (or in the headers) of the iframe URL that kibana let us  share

5) We need to route the requests coming from an external client

6) We need to disable access to the configuration pages of kibana

I need a very stable solution, I am trying different solution like reverse proxy but not works well yet!

Comment: What the difference between the user auth?
Do each user have different data that he can see, or different visualisation?

Comment: Different DATA and also maybe in the future different visualization.

Comment: Does each document have field that distinguish between the users?

Comment: yes they are saved in a different folders which each folder is for a user

Answer (score 0):

This isn't anything to do with Pyramid per-say - but it sounds like you need to come up with a system that can act as a reverse proxy for your dashboard by issuing controlled requests to the backend and then turning those into responses back to the original client.

Comment: You need to define your own API and then translate those requests into properly formed requests to kibana. You can then parse the response and fix it up so that it looks like it came from you (probably replacing urls to assets, etc).